# fnmatch.fnmatch use a pattern to exclude sub directories

Tags: python, azure-storage, wildcard, azure-cli, fnmatch

I have a directory structure like this

```
rootFolder/
    - some.jar
    - another.jar
    subDirectory/
                -some1.jar
```

I only want to get the files in the rootFolder and not the subDirectory (some.jar and another.jar).

I have also tried the following pattern but I was trying to do it without specifying the name of the subDirectory in the pattern. See [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJwN6KuXd) with directory name specified.

I have also used pattern like '*.jar' but it also includes the subDirectory file.

Any suggestions?

**Background**

I am trying to write a generic script for uploading via az cli; the function I am using is `upload-batch` and it internally uses fnmatch where I only have control of the pattern I pass using the `--pattern` flag. See [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload_batch)

Below command is being used:

```
az storage file upload-batch  --account-name myaccountname --destination dest-directory  --destination-path test/ --source rootFolder --pattern "*.jar" --dryrun
```

Comment: Adding some background information to the question how you create the input for `fnmatch` or what you want to achieve at the end might help to provide an answer that fits your use case.

Comment: I have provide some background as well

Comment: Then your real problem is not how to match file names using `fnmatch` but how to specify the arguments for `az storage blob upload-batch...` with the background information that the documentation refers to `fnmatch` for the `--pattern` option. Please show in your question the command you would like to use, even with a non-working pattern. Maybe you can specify the source directory as `./root` and use a pattern `./*.jar` or `/path/to/root` and `/path/to/root/*.jar`? (I don't have this `ac` program available for testing.)

Comment: I have added an example command I am using although I am not sure this would be possible by just specifying a pattern since if you second example is looked at one would atleast need another condition to exclude the `/` or if we can combine the '*.jar' and ' */** ' in one pattern that would do the trick.

Comment: Your example command doesn't seem to match the example directory structure. What happens when you try patterns `"./*.jar"` or `"sourceFolder/*.jar"`?

Comment: I have updated the command to match the example folder structure

Comment: Any results with patterns `"./*.jar"` or `"sourceFolder/*.jar"`?

Comment: No I have tried both do not work although the second one you have suggested does work but also matches the nested files see [python compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/SyGo7E1Vd).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question. Comments might get deleted and you make it harder for others to help you when the information is scattered in comments. Did you try with the actual command or only with your own Python code? I don't know how the pattern is actually applied to the affected files. Is the source code of the CLI available?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the original question which seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as it asked about matching file names using `fnmatch` instead of how to specify a pattern for the [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload_batch).

You could use `re` instead of `fnmatch`

```
import re
testdata = ['hello.jar', 'foo.jar', 'test/hello.jar', 'test/another/hello.jar', 'hello.html', 'test/another/hello.jaring']
for val in testdata :
    print(val, bool(re.match(r"[^/]*\.jar$", val)))
```

prints

```
hello.jar True                                                                                                                                                                              
foo.jar True                                                                                                                                                                                
test/hello.jar False                                                                                                                                                                        
test/another/hello.jar False                                                                                                                                                                
hello.html False                                                                                                                                                                            
test/another/hello.jaring False
```

or add a second check for `/`

```
import fnmatch
pattern = '*.jar'
testdata = ['hello.jar', 'foo.jar', 'test/hello.jar', 'test/another/hello.jar', 'hello.html', 'test/another/hello.jaring']
for val in testdata :
    print(val, fnmatch.fnmatch(val, pattern) and not fnmatch.fnmatch(val, '*/*'))
```

Comment: I have provided some background as to why I want to use fnmatch and I only have control over the pattern.